# Are there Kryptonians on Prime Earth and does/did New Krypton exist there?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-rebirth, new-krypton-saga

Note: Don't spoil anything past the *Superman Reborn* crossover.

I've been reading *Superman*, *Action Comics*, and a little bit of *Batman* and just thought of something. 
I was surprised when I looked up New Krypton to see what had happened to it during The New 52 but found that the whole arc took place on New Earth and was Pre-New 52. So, when I looked up the DC Wikia page about it on Prime Earth, it did not exist!

**So, here's my question: is it known if New Krypton does/did or doesn't exist on Prime Earth?**

Comment: How do I get this answered, is there a ‘re-ask’ question button?

Comment: You can bump the question to the homepage with an [edit] but it's strongly recommended to actually add info or clarify things (don't just bump it for it to be more visible). As for the answering, if no one has answered yet, it might just be because they're still looking (if there are people looking to answer). They might ask for more clarification in the comments, be sure to reply to them if that happens :)

Comment: As a side comment, I've seen you posting various posts about current DC comics and apparently willing to discuss them. When you get to 20 rep, you'll be able to do that in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe). Feel free to ask! I myself would be happy to, ping me anytime :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There are both Kryptonians and a "New Krypton" on Prime Earth.

#### Kryptonians

There are a few Kryptonians (I count 14) that have made appearances, including:

- [Superman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kal-El_(Prime_Earth)) (duh!)
- [Kara Zor-El](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kara_Zor-El_(Prime_Earth)) ([also duh!](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marvel_dc/images/8/85/Supergirl_Vol_6_1.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/326?cb=20110919204233))
- [General Zod](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marvel_dc/images/f/ff/Action_Comics_Vol_2_23.2_Zod.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/325?cb=20130911215002) (Dru-Zod)
- [Zor-El](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Zor-El_(Prime_Earth))
- [Ursa](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Ursa_(Prime_Earth))
- [Alura In-Ze](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Alura_In-Ze_(Prime_Earth))

Others: [Jonathan Lane Kent](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Jonathan_Lane_Kent_(Prime_Earth)), [Rao](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Rao_(Prime_Earth)), [Xa-Du](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Xa-Du_(Prime_Earth)), [Lor-Zod](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Lor-Zod_(Prime_Earth)), [Faora Hu-Ul](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Faora_Hu-Ul_(Prime_Earth)), [Lar-On](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Lar-On_(Prime_Earth)), [Jan-Al](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Jan-Al_(Prime_Earth)), [Kon](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kon_(Prime_Earth)).

#### New Krypton

Revealed after the 4 part cross-over in March of 2017, the New Krypton on Prime Earth is called [Jekuul](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Jekuul).

> A planet conquered by Zod, that he makes his home. It is called "New Krypton" for the first time in *Action Comics #996*

> [image: Superman on Jekuul]

> In the [next panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNV5q.jpg) the planet is identified as Jekuul.